# Regexp delimiter "::" Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have an IPv6 address as

```
> puts $addr
3ffe:0:4:ff00::fc:5
```

I would like to split this into 2 groups of

- 3ffe:0:4:ff00
- fc:5

I've tried the "split" command but it doesn't work. Regexp gives the following result:

```
> regexp -all -- {(\S+)[set z](\S+)} $addr match g1 g2
1
> puts $g1
3ff
> puts $g2
:0:4:ff00::fc:5
```

Any suggestions on a way to split them?

Comment: `(.*)::(.*)` maybe?

Comment: That doesnt work. The problem with IPv6 address is that it also has a single ":" in the string. And the regexp will match on the single ":" and split before going ahead.

Comment: `(.*)::(.*)` will never match on a single ":"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` only splits on a single character. What you can do is to swap `::` to something else and split on that something else. For example, let's say it's impossible to have the character `@` in the string, so you can replace this first, then split on `@`:

```
% set sub [string map {"::" "@"} $addr]
3ffe:0:4:ff00@fc:5
% set groups [split $sub "@"]
3ffe:0:4:ff00 fc:5
```

Otherwise if you want to use regex, you can match:

```
% regexp {(.+)::(.+)} $addr - part1 part2
1
% puts $part1
3ffe:0:4:ff00
% puts $part2
fc:5
```

---

The expression you were using `(\S+)[set z](\S+)` actually tries to match in this order:

1. Non-space characters
2. Any one character from `s`, `e`, `t`, `<space>` or `z`
3. Non-space characters

So that `(\S+)` would match `(3ff)`, `[set z]` would match `e` and `(\S+)` would match the remainder of the string. If you wanted to have the variable contained by `z`, you would need to use something a bit more like this (braces prevent substitution of `[set z]` and `\` but quotes don't, as a result, you will have to escape the backslashes if you allow substitution):

```
regexp "(\\S+)[set z](\\S+)" $addr match g1 g2
```

or

```
regexp "(\\S+)${z}(\\S+)" $addr match g1 g2
```

<sub>I removed the `-all` flag since there was only one match, so in this case, it was not necessary, though you can keep the `--`</sub>

Comment: @PJProudhon ok? if you are referring to my statement, it was made in context to the tags of the question

Comment: @PJProudhon this was not a statement about the regex flavour though. `split` is a string function in Tcl (that does not take a regex) and the OP mentioned trying it at first, but found it did not work. It did sound like you were coming out of nowhere so I was a bit talen aback, but it's fine if you want to keep your comment.

Comment: Considering your feedback I find my comment too much confusing. I'm then deleting it.

Comment: `regexp -all -- "(\\S+)[set z](\\S+)" $val match f1 f2`  worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: There's quite a few characters that are extremely rare in text, such as `\uFFFC` (unicode object replacement), that are useful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`textutil::split` package from tcllib](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html)

```
$ tclsh
% package require textutil::split
0.8
% set parts [::textutil::split::splitx "3ffe:0:4:ff00::fc:5" "::"]
3ffe:0:4:ff00 fc:5
```

Comment: Splitting based on a regular expression is a solved problem. Use the library, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on a way to split them?

Keep it simple, using [`string map`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34):

```
% set addr 3ffe:0:4:ff00::fc:5
3ffe:0:4:ff00::fc:5
% lassign [string map {:: " "} $addr] pt1 pt2
% puts $pt1
3ffe:0:4:ff00
% puts $pt2
fc:5
```

Comment: I noticed that my answer is just a simplification of Jerry's using a `string map`/ `subst` combo. This is not necessary, in my view.

Comment: @Nasir: You should accept then one answer that worked for you best, first, or provided the most valuable insight to you ...

Comment: thanks for reminding. I updated the accepted answer.